# How find a summ of days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with data below:

```
organization , number of request, date number of request
organization1, ID1139151,         2017-03-15 13:10:01.000
organization1, ID1139152,         2017-03-15 14:31:05.000
organization2, ID1139153,         2017-03-16 10:38:08.000
organization2, ID1139154,         2017-03-16 09:26:04.000
organization2, ID1139155,         2017-03-16 18:09:15.000
organization2, ID1139156,         2017-03-16 20:14:29.000
organization3, ID1139157,         2017-03-23 11:18:18.000
```

Help me to find a summ of days by every organization with help of SQL query.

Result:

```
organization , date number of request
organization1, 2
organization2, 4
organization3, 1
```

Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (

   [organization] varchar(50) NOT NULL,

   [number of request] varchar(15) NOT NULL,

   [date_number_of_request] datetime NOT NULL,
     )

INSERT INTO Mytable

VALUES 

('organization1','ID1139151','2017-03-15 13:10:01.000'),

('organization1','ID1139152','2017-03-15 14:31:05.000'),

('organization2','ID1139153','2017-03-16 10:38:08.000'),

('organization2','ID1139154','2017-03-16 09:26:04.000'),

('organization2','ID1139155','2017-03-16 18:09:15.000'),

('organization2','ID1139156','2017-03-16 20:14:29.000'),

('organization3','ID1139157','2017-03-23 11:18:18.000');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple group by would do what you need:

```
SELECT  organization, 
        COUNT([date_number_of_request]) As [date number of request]
FROM Mytable 
GROUP BY organization
```

Result:

```
organization , date number of request
organization1, 2
organization2, 4
organization3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use the concept of group by in sql like below

```
Select organization ,count([date_number_of_request]) as 'date number of request'
from Mytable group by organization order by organization
```